# Prevent LOAD DATA INFILE from escaping double double quotes

Tags: mysql, csv, escaping, load-data-infile

I have csv data like the following:

```
"E12 98003";1085894;"HELLA";"8GS007949261";"";1
"5 3/4"";652493;"HELLA";"9HD140976001";"";1
```

Some fields are included in double quotes. The problem is that
as you may see in the second line the data in the first column contains a double quotation mark at the end as part of the data.

I tried something along the lines of:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE file.csv
INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

but it will use the quotation mark in the data to escape the field enclosing quotation mark. I also tried `ESCAPED BY ''` and `ESCAPED BY '\\'` with no success.
Is there a way to stop the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command from escaping the double double quotation marks? 
Or should I parse the csv and put double quotation marks when there is only one?
I am parsing the files anyway using powershell to change the encoding to utf8. Is there some way to fix this quickly there? My powershell code:

```
function Convert-FileToUTF8 {

    param([string]$infile,
          [string]$outfile,
          [System.Int32]$encodingCode)

    $encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($encodingCode)
    $text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($infile, $encoding)
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($outfile, $text)

}
```

Ok, I did it using a .NET regular expression to fix the csv. It is costly, but not too much.
I wrote

```
$text = [regex]::Replace($text, "(?m)(?<!^)(?<!\;)""(?!\;)(?!\r?$)", '""');
```

just before the last line in the function and it seems to work ok. Since I am a novice in regular expressions this could probably be improved.

Comment: The main problem is that the input data is invalid CSV format because the double quotation mark belonging to the data should have been doubled (escaped).  So the question becomes: where did you get this invalid CSV from, and what can you do to fix it?

Comment: It was exported from a third party software. Unfortunately I have no control on how the csv is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that the input data constitutes invalid CSV syntax, as stated in [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), paragraph 7:

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote.

But in your PowerShell script you could try to fix this issue with an extra line, using the [replace method](http://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) on *$text*, once you got it's value:

```
$text = $text.Replace('"";', '""";')
```

This should be enough, as the loader will deal well with unescaped double quotes if they appear elsewhere in the data, as stated on [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) (my highlight):

> If the field begins with the `ENCLOSED BY` character, instances of that character are recognized as terminating a field value ***only if followed by*** the field or line `TERMINATED BY` sequence.

Of course, if the badly formatted CSV has data that contains `";`, then you still have a problem. But it is very hard to determine whether such an occurrence terminates the data or should be seen as part of the data, even for humans :-)

Another thing to pay attention to as found on [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

> If the input values are not necessarily enclosed within quotation marks, use `OPTIONALLY` before the `ENCLOSED` BY keywords.

Comment: I am afraid that your solution will take care only for the unescaped double quotes at the end of the data.

Comment: Yes, but MySql Load will treat inner quotes as they are, even if unescaped, on the condition they are not followed by a field or line delimiter.

Comment: It looks fine... Still, what bothers me is that this condition cannot be guaranteed...

Comment: Updated my answer with some references. You are right, if the CSV is not canonical, all guarantee is lost. There was a good reason for that CSV standard...

Comment: I tried to do it with a regular expression in the end, but your guidance was extremely helpful.

Comment: Good. Note that in extreme situations some lines could have multiple interpretations, like if columns 3 and 4 were represented like this `""HELLA";"GOTO";"8G"`. There is no way to be sure which of the two `";"` is the real separator and which is just data.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Just as you said if the CSV was not created correctly it cannot be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

In addition: importing CSV files in MySQL having the values enclosed in quotes works fine when using the ENCLOSED BY option.. UNLESS the enclosed field is the last field in a row, AND you used Excel to create the CSV file. Excel omits the field separator after the last field in a row. MySQL doesn't mind... unless the last field is enclosed in quotes. Then the import terminates at that line.

Examples:
This works fine: ...;value2;value3 (no trailing separator)
This also works fine ...;"value 2";value3 (value enclosed in quotes)
This also works fine ...;value 2;"value3"; (last field value enclosed in quotes and trailing separator)
But this breaks the import: ...;value2;"value 3" (last field value enclosed in quotes and no trailing separator)

Took me some time to figure this out; hope sharing this saves somebody else that time.